# iOS In App Purchase - some users get double charged

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

We have received some emails lately where users complain about getting double charged for consumable in app purchases. I do not know, how this is possible. Furthermore it seems only a few users are experiencing this kind of problem. But if the do, it happens multiple times.
Do I miss something? The quantity is 1 by default, isn't it?
Do you have experienced problems with double charges? I have found a lot of users complaining about being double charged over various apps. Is this a problem of Apple/iTunes or are many developers doing something wrong?

Here is the relevant code for the transaction. I only allow one transaction at a time, using a member variable *transactionRunning* and checking the SKPaymentQueue how many transactions are in the queue.

Any comment or experience would be appreciated.
Any help to fix this would be highly appreciated.

```
- (void)purchaseProduct:(NSString*)productIdentifier
{
    NSArray * array = [SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue].transactions;
    if (transactionRunning == false && [array count] == 0)
    {
        transactionRunning = true;      
        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:productIdentifier];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
    }
}

- (void)finishTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction wasSuccessful:(BOOL)wasSuccessful
{    
    transactionRunning = false;
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {        
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self provideContent:transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];
                [self finishTransaction:transaction wasSuccessful:YES];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, in my case the problem wasn't in the code.

One day I saw a lot of refunds.

Asked Apple, that said that was due to a technical issue.And now the problem was solved.
And that refunds were for double in-app charges.

nothing else information.... thanks for the consideration, Apple